# Invalid read of size 1 in valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind, invalidation

I am running a piece of code which has 2 functions and run valgrind, getting invalid read of size 1. we are not able to identify the problem please help

```
RrSSystemIntf_i::RrSSystemIntf_i()
{
  RrXmlReader cfgReader;
  char* configFile = cfgFile;
  char* pss;
  U pssId;

  if (ROK != cfgReader.readConfig(configFile, (char*)"ABCD", (char*)"RR_NODES",
                                  &pss)) {
    RR_ALERT("RrSSystemIntf_i: readConfig failed. exiting...");
    _exit();
  }

  pssId = atoi(pss);
}


int RrXmlReader::readConfig(char*& confFile, char* elem_type, char* val_type,
                            char** ret_val)
{
  reader.getValue(curContext, val_type, value);

  if (NULL == value) {
    RR_ALERT("XmlFactory::rrNodes : Config Error: %s missing from %s", val_type,
             elem_type);
    return RFAILED;
  }

  string returnStr;
  returnStr = std::string(value);
  *ret_val  = (char*)(returnStr.c_str());
  return ROK;
}
```

Valgrind trace:

```
==30007== Invalid read of size 1
==30007==    at 0x33296345CA: ____strtol_l_internal (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
==30007==    by 0x52D5A64: RrS7SystemIntf_i::RrS7SystemIntf_i() (stdlib.h:336)
==30007==    by 0x52AA9E7: RrObInit::initOb(int, char**) (RrObInit.cpp:360)
==30007==    by 0x52ACF6D: RrObInit::getInstance() (RrObInit.cpp:636)
==30007==    by 0x52AE909: tst (RrTst.cpp:515)
==30007==    by 0x4C12694: Init (gen.c:581)
==30007==    by 0x4C1135C: Main (mtss.c:484)
==30007==    by 0x52ADD7B: main (RrTst.cpp:225)
==30007==  Address 0x8e9dc28 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 28 free'd
==30007==    at 0x4A05743: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:346)
==30007==    by 0x52FC330: RrXmlReader::readConfig(char*&, char*, char*, char**)    (basic_string.h:233)
==30007==    by 0x52D590B: RrS7SystemIntf_i::RrgS7SystemIntf_i() (RrS7System_i.cpp:325)
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable, that never ends well.

Comment: the cstring returned by `c_str()` is only valid as long as the base `string` exists, dereferencing `ret_val` after the function returns will be undefined behavior.

Comment: Unrelated to your bug, but you should take C-style strings as `char const *` if you do not intend to modify them, instead of casting away const. That will help to prevent other bugs.

Comment: This is a pretty sparse post... What have you tried so far to find the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem starts from the line:

```
*ret_val  = (char*)(returnStr.c_str());
```

You are returning, through `ret_val`, an address that is going to be invalid as soon as you return from `readConfig`.

Valgrind catches the memory access problem when you execute:

```
pssId = atoi(pss);
```

since `pss` points to invalid memory at that point.

My suggestion:

Change `readConfig` to

```
int RrXmlReader::readConfig(char*& confFile, char* elem_type, char* val_type,
                            std::string& ret_val)
```